# Need help getting IE11 working with Angular 1.5 / Angular 10 (ngUpgrade project)

Tags: angular, webpack, internet-explorer-11, polyfills

Im having issues getting IE11 working in my ngUpgrade project. I tried everything I saw with other having similar issues. Im am not using angular cli. Stand alone webpack. I was hoping someone can look at my code and see if there are any apparent issues with my setup.

Here is what Im seeing an IE11 along with a blank page.
[image: Here is the error i get in IE11]

main.ts

```
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { setAngularLib } from '@angular/upgrade/static';
declare var angular: angular.IAngularStatic;

import { AppModule } from './app.module.ts';

// Scss
import './core/styles/temporary.scss'

export function importAll(r) {
  r.keys().forEach(r);
};

// Typescript
importAll(require.context('../src', true, /module\.ts$/));
importAll(require.context('../src', true, /(^(?!.*(spec|module)\.ts).*\.ts)$/));

// Coffescript
importAll(require.context('../src', true, /module\.coffee$/));
importAll(require.context('../src', true, /(^(?!.*(spec|module)\.coffee).*\.coffee)$/));

// Images
importAll(require.context('../src', true, /.*\.(png|svg|ico|webmanifest)$/));

// Translations
importAll(require.context('../src', true, /.*\.json$/));

setAngularLib(angular);
platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

vendor.ts

```
//IE11 polyfills
require("../node_modules/core-js/es5/index")
require("../node_modules/core-js/es6/symbol")
require("../node_modules/core-js/es6/object")
require("../node_modules/core-js/es6/function")
require("../node_modules/core-js/es6/parse-int")
require("../node_modules/core-js/es6/parse-float")
require("../node_modules/core-js/es6/number")
require("../node_modules/core-js/es6/math")
require("../node_modules/core-js/es6/string")
require("../node_modules/core-js/es6/date")
require("../node_modules/core-js/es6/regexp")
require("../node_modules/core-js/es6/map")
require("../node_modules/core-js/es6/weak-map")
require("../node_modules/core-js/es6/set")
require("../node_modules/core-js/es6/array")
require("../node_modules/core-js/es6/reflect")
require("../node_modules/core-js/es7/object")
require("../node_modules/core-js/es7/array")
require("../node_modules/core-js/es7/reflect")
require("../node_modules/classlist.js")
require("../node_modules/web-animations-js")
require("../node_modules/reflect-metadata")
require("../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone")

require("../node_modules/messageformat/messageformat.js")
require("../node_modules/angular/angular.js")
require("../node_modules/angular-google-analytics/dist/angular-google-analytics.js")
require("../node_modules/@uirouter/angularjs/release/angular-ui-router.js")
require("../vendor-js/lodash.js")
require("../vendor-js/ui-bootstrap.js")
require("../node_modules/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.js")

ect....
```

babelrc

```
{
  "presets": [
    ["@babel/preset-env",{
      "modules": false
    }]
  ],
  "plugins": ["babel-plugin-angularjs-annotate"]
}
```

package.json

```
{
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "NODE_ENV=development webpack --config webpack.dev.js",
    "prod": "NODE_ENV=production webpack --config webpack.prod.js",
    "tsc": "tsc"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "Edge > 13",
    "Firefox > 50",
    "Safari > 10",
    "Explorer > 10",
    "Chrome > 60"
  ],
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/schematics": "^9.1.8",
    "@angular/common": "10.1.2",
    "@angular/compiler": "10.1.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "10.1.3",
    "@angular/core": "10.1.3",
    "@angular/forms": "10.1.3",
    "@angular/http": "7.2.16",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "10.1.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "10.1.3",
    "@angular/router": "10.1.2",
    "@angular/upgrade": "10.1.3",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "7.0.0",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "12.0.0",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "6.0.0",
    "@uirouter/angularjs": "1.0.26",
    "angular": "1.8.0",
    "angular-animate": "1.8.0",
    "angular-cookies": "1.8.0",
    "angular-file-upload": "2.5.0",
    "angular-google-analytics": "1.1.8",
    "angular-locker": "2.0.5",
    "angular-messages": "1.8.0",
    "angular-mocks": "1.8.0",
    "angular-phone-input": "^1.0.1",
    "angular-sanitize": "1.8.0",
    "angular-touch": "1.8.0",
    "angular-translate": "2.18.2",
    "angular-translate-interpolation-messageformat": "2.18.2",
    "angular-translate-loader-static-files": "2.18.2",
    "angular-translate-storage-cookie": "2.18.2",
    "angular-translate-storage-local": "2.18.2",
    "angular-utils-pagination": "0.11.1",
    "angular-validation-match": "1.9.0",
    "angularjs-rails-resource": "2.3.1",
    "classlist.js": "^1.1.20150312",
    "clipboard": "2.0.6",
    "highcharts": "7.0.2",
    "highcharts-ng": "1.2.1",
    "merge-jsons-webpack-plugin": "1.0.21",
    "messageformat": "2.3.0",
    "moment": "2.26.0",
    "ng-device-detector": "5.1.4",
    "ng-idle": "1.3.2",
    "ngclipboard": "2.0.0",
    "ngmap": "1.18.5",
    "npm": "6.14.5",
    "popper.js": "^1.16.1",
    "re-tree": "0.1.7",
    "reflect-metadata": "0.1.13",
    "rxjs": "6.5.5",
    "ua-device-detector": "1.1.8",
    "web-animations-js": "^2.3.2",
    "zone.js": "0.11.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "7.10.2",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-object-assign": "7.10.1",
    "@babel/polyfill": "7.10.1",
    "@babel/preset-env": "7.10.2",
    "@types/angular": "^1.6.57",
    "@types/webpack-env": "1.15.2",
    "autoprefixer": "9.8.0",
    "babel-loader": "8.1.0",
    "babel-plugin-angularjs-annotate": "0.10.0",
    "coffee-loader": "1.0.0",
    "coffeescript": "2.5.1",
    "css-loader": "3.5.3",
    "del": "5.1.0",
    "file-loader": "6.0.0",
    "filemanager-webpack-plugin": "2.0.5",
    "html-loader": "1.1.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "4.3.0",
    "jasmine-core": "3.5.0",
    "jquery": "3.5.1",
    "karma": "5.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "3.1.0",
    "karma-coffee-preprocessor": "1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "3.3.1",
    "karma-ng-html2js-preprocessor": "1.0.0",
    "karma-phantomjs-launcher": "1.0.4",
    "karma-requirejs": "1.1.0",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "0.9.0",
    "node-sass": "4.14.1",
    "normalizr": "3.6.0",
    "postcss": "7.0.32",
    "q": "1.5.1",
    "require-dir": "1.2.0",
    "requirejs": "2.3.6",
    "sass-loader": "8.0.2",
    "string-replace-loader": "2.3.0",
    "style-loader": "1.2.1",
    "ts-loader": "7.0.5",
    "typescript": "3.9.5",
    "vinyl-paths": "3.0.1",
    "webpack": "4.43.0",
    "webpack-cli": "3.3.11",
    "webpack-merge": "4.2.2"
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "natives": "1.1.3"
  }
}
```

tsconfig

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es2015",
    "lib": ["es5", "es6", "dom"],
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "allowJs": true,
    "outDir": "foo"
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

webpack.common

```
const moment = require("./node_modules/moment/moment.js")

const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");
const MergeJsonWebpackPlugin = require("merge-jsons-webpack-plugin");
const FileManagerPlugin = require('filemanager-webpack-plugin');


const dest = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? './dist' : './dev'

const cacheBustId = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? '-' + moment('123120202', 'YYYYMMDD') : ''

module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [{
        test: /\.(html)$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'html-loader',
            options: {
              minimize: false,
              //minimize: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? true : false,
            },
          },
        ],
      },{
        test: /\.(js|coffee)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: "babel-loader",
          options: {
            presets: [
              "@babel/env"
            ],
            plugins: [
              "@babel/plugin-transform-object-assign"
            ],
        }
      }
      },{
        "test": /\.coffee$/,
        "exclude": /node_modules/,
        "use": {
          loader: "coffee-loader"
        }
      },{
        test: /\.coffee$/,
        loader: 'string-replace-loader',
        options: {
          multiple: [
            { search: "'en-us': 'en-us.json'", replace: "'en-us': 'en-us" + cacheBustId + ".json'" },
            { search: "'es-us': 'es-us.json'", replace: "'es-us': 'es-us" + cacheBustId + ".json'" },
            { search: "'fr-ca': 'fr-ca.json'", replace: "'fr-ca': 'fr-ca" + cacheBustId + ".json'" }
          ]
        }
      },{
        // Mark files inside `@angular/core` as using SystemJS style dynamic imports.
        // Removing this will cause deprecation warnings to appear.
        test: /[\/\\]@angular[\/\\]core[\/\\].+\.js$/,
        parser: { system: true },  // enable SystemJS
      },{
        test: /\.tsx?$/,
        loader: 'ts-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/,
      },{
        test: /\.(css|scss)$/,
        use: [{
          loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
        },{
          loader: "css-loader"
        },{
          loader: "sass-loader"
        }]
      },{
        test: /\.(woff(2)?|ttf|eot)(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'file-loader',
            options: {
              name: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ?  '[name]-[contentHash].[ext]' : '[name].[ext]',
              outputPath: '../fonts/'
            }
          }
        ]
      },{
        test: /\.(png|svg)$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'file-loader',
            options: {
              name: '[name].[ext]',
              outputPath: '../img/'
            }
          }
        ]
      },{
        test: /\.(ico|webmanifest)$/,
        loader: 'file-loader?name=[name].[ext]'
      },
    ],
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: './src/index.html',
      filename: '../index.html',
      hash: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? true : false
    }),
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      filename: '../css/styles.css'
    }),
    new MergeJsonWebpackPlugin({
      "output": {
        "groupBy": [
          {
            "pattern": "./src/**/en-us.json",
            "fileName": process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? "../locales/en-us" + cacheBustId + ".json" : "../locales/en-us.json"
          },{
            "pattern": "./src/**/es-us.json",
            "fileName": process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? "../locales/es-us" + cacheBustId + ".json" : "../locales/es-us.json"
          },{
            "pattern": "./src/**/fr-ca.json",
            "fileName": process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? "../locales/fr-ca" + cacheBustId + ".json" : "../locales/fr-ca.json"
          }
        ]
      },
    })
  ]
};
```

webpack.dev

```
const merge = require('webpack-merge');
const common = require('./webpack.common.js');

module.exports = merge(common, {
  mode: "development",
  entry: {
    poly: "@babel/polyfill",
    vendor: './src/vendor.js',
    app: "./src/main.ts"
  },
  output: {
    filename: '[name].js',
    path: __dirname + '/dev/js'
  },
  watch: true,
  stats: 'normal',
});
```

Comment: If you want it to work in IE11, start by adding IE11 to your browserslist

Comment: Its there ```"Explorer > 10"```

Comment: You have to create es5 code to support IE11. So you might want to look into differential serving with webpack.

Comment: I agree with the suggestion given by **Ruben** for adding IE 11 to the browser list. Further, you need to set `"target": "es5"` in the **tsconfig.json** file to make your site work in the IE browser.

Comment: Had to go the differential loading route. Thanks @fridoo

Comment: @blankpage985, from your last comment. It looks like you had found the solution for the issue by using the differential loading route. I suggest you post your solution as an answer for this thread and try to mark your own answer as an answer to this question. It can help other community members in the future in similar kinds of issues. Thanks for your understanding